# Yii gridview How to set editable option based on the data

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

This is my grid view code

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'toolbar'=> [
        ['content'=>
            Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add New', ['create'],['class'=>'btn btn-shadow btn-success'])
        ],
        '{toggleData}',
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute'=>'Name',
            'vAlign'=>GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'Age',
            'vAlign'=>GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            'value'=>'Age',
            'width'=>'5%',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'Address',
            'vAlign'=>GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
            'attribute'=>'Status',
            'vAlign'=>GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            'hAlign'=>GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
            'width'=>'15%',
            'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search Status...'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ],
            'value'=>function($model){
                return ($model->Status=='0'?'Pending':($model->Status=='1'?'Accepted':'Rejected'));},
            'filter'=>['Pending','Diterima'],
            'label' => 'Status',
            'refreshGrid'=>true,
            'editableOptions'=>[
                'format' => Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,
                'asPopover' => true,
                'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
                'data'=>['0'=>'Pending', '1'=>'Accepted', '2'=>'Rejected'],
                'options' => ['class'=>'form-control'],
            ]
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '
                <li>{view}</li>
                <li>{update}</li>
                <li>{delete}</li>',
            'dropdown'=>true,
            'dropdownOptions'=>['class'=>'pull-right'],
            'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
        ],
    ],
    'panel'=>[
        'type'=>GridView::TYPE_DEFAULT,
    ]
]); ?>
```

Help me with the Status attribute. The result from this gridview is like this :
[image]

what i want is like this : 
[image]

So, it's like when the Status is Pending, the editableOption is on.But when the Status is Accepted or Rejected, the editableOption is disable. Is that possible ?

Comment: `'data'=>['0'=>'Pending'],`

Comment: well, it's like create an if statement for turn the editableOption on and off. The 'data' is just to change the status. @Anant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Change **value option** of **Status Attribute**.

Change in value option of Status Attribute.

```
[
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute'=>'Status',
          // ------- your code ------------
        'format'=>'raw',
        'value'=>function($model){
              if($model->Status=='0')
              {
                // if status =0 than create button and append with string
                $btn='<button type="button" id='.$model->id.' class="btn btn-default ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>';
                return 'Pending'.$btn;
              }
              else
              {
                return($model->Status=='1'?'Accepted':'Rejected');
              }
            },
        // ------- your code ------------

    ],
```

Comment: the <button> isn't show as button, it just show as string. the result is like "Pending<button type="button" id='1' class="btn btn-default ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>" @Yasin Patel

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you have asked, if you have used editableOptions, then

1. For Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST type -> use 'editableButtonOptions' => [ 'disabled' => $data->your_status_variable_condition],
2. For any other type add readonly property

   'readonly'      => function($data){
   return $data->your_status_variable_condition;
   },

I hope it helps someone who is looking for the same issue